# Removing nickname from localStorage string

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to check localStorage for a nickname and if it includes the nickname remove it from the localStorage.

```js
window.removeNickname = (n) => {
    const names = localStorage['nicknames'].split(','); // Output = ["NAME 1", "NAME 2", "NAME 3"]
    if (names.includes(n)) {
        // HOW CAN I REMOVE THE NAME FROM THE LOCALSTORAGE HERE AND REPLACE THE LOCALSTORAGE NICKNAMES.
    }
};
    
removeNickname('NAME 2');
```

Comment: [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/api_storage.asp) is a key/value pair storage and the `value` is always a `string` type, you need to replace the string with a new string without what you want... if you know the name, a simple `localStorage.setItem("nicknames", localStorage.getItem("nicknames").replace("balexandre,", ""))` will suffice - try in the browser console 

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove the item from the array with split and set the new array as your nicknames.
Splice removes the items from array starting from the index that you mentioned in the first argument and removes as many elements as you set in the second argument.

```
window.removeNickname = (n) => { 
  const names = localStorage['nicknames'].split(','); // Output = ["NAME 1", "NAME 2", "NAME 3"]
  if (names.includes(n)) {
    localStorage.setItem(nicknames, names.splice(names.indexOf(n), 1));
  }
};
```

Comment: You have an error in the code - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @entlassungspapi Yeah I just forgot to set the closing parentheses, thanks for mentioning it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for [**localDataStorage**](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), a utility I authored. With **localDataStorage** you can create and manipulate Array Keys and store the value in localStorage. Some examples:

Create and initialize an Array Key in localStorage called *nicknames* with 3 element values:

```
> lds.push( 'nicknames', 'Mac', 'Bill', 'Will' );
```

Query the Array Key for a certain element:

```
> lds.contains( 'nicknames', 'Bill' );
  true
```

Remove an element from the Array Key (specifying a value literal):

```
> lds.pull( 'nicknames', 'Bill' );
```

Get the updated key value:

```
> let newKey = lds.get( 'nicknames' );
['Mac', 'Will']
```

So your application might go something like this:

```
const removeNickname = (n) => {
    lds.pull( 'nicknames', n );
    return lds.get( 'nicknames' );
};

const addNickname = (n) => {
    lds.push( 'nicknames', n ); // appends to array
    return lds.get( 'nicknames' );
};

updatedNicknamesArray = removeNickname( 'Tom' );

updatedNicknamesArray = addNickname( 'Tim' );
```